# Помогите исправить выход за границы массива

Tags: java

Массив заполняется змейкой по кругу.

Возникает ошибка:

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1 at para13.main(para13.java:20)".

Помогите исправить, пожалуйста. Код:

```
public class para13{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int z = 6;
        int[][] a = new int[z][z];
        int x = 0, y = -1, l = 1;
        boolean ch;

        for (int i = 1; i<z*z; ++i){
            if ((y+1<z) && (a[x][y+1] == 0)){
                y = y + 1;
                a[x][y] = i;
            }
            else{
                if ((x+1<z) && (a[x+1][y] == 0)){
                    x = x + 1;
                    a[x][y] = i;
                }
                else{
                    if ((y-1<z) && (a[x][y-1] == 0)){
                        y = y - 1;
                        a[x][y] = i; 
                    }
                    else {
                        if ((x-1<z) && (a[x-1][y] == 0 )){
                            x = x - 1;
                            a[x][y] = i;
                        }
                        }
                    }

                }
                //System.out.print("x " + x + " ");
                //System.out.println("y " + y);
                //printMas(a); 


        }
         printMas(a); 

    }
    public static void printMas(int[][] b) { //вывод массива
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
                        System.out.print(b[i][j] + "\t");
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }
        System.out.println(); 
    }

}
```

Comment: У вас некая запутанная логика заполнения массива, и видимо либо логика неправильная, либо вы неправильно её реализовали. Но без знания этой логики сказать что-то тяжело.

Comment: Заполняю змейкой.

Comment: А строка 20 это где будет?

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja if ((y-1<z) && (a[x][y-1] == 0)). Это 3 if

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как-то так должно работать (указан только проблемный кусок кода)

```
                if ((y-1<z) && (y>0) && (a[x][y-1] == 0)){
                    y = y - 1;
                    a[x][y] = i; 
                }
                else {
                    if ((x-1<z) && (x>0) && (a[x-1][y] == 0 )){
                        x = x - 1;
                        a[x][y] = i;
                    }
                }
```

Вы забываете проверять на достижение нижней границы массива при декременте индекса.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

В одном из `if` у вас же нет никакого ограничения снизу на `y`, который все время уменьшается на 1 (по факту он у вас может уйти и в минус, но упадет уже при `y == 0`, т.к. обращаетесь к `y-1`)

```
if ((y-1<z) && (a[x][y-1] == 0)){
   y = y - 1;
   a[x][y] = i; 
}
```

А как подсказывают, и в следующем `if` у вас аналогичная проблема, но уже с `x`.

Вы все-таки попробуйте продебажить прежде чем спросить :)
Дальше уж думайте сами, так как дальнейшее решение данной проблемы за вас мне кажется неприемлемым для сообщества.

Comment: В след. `if` та же беда и с `x` :)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja Угу, и правда, мне что-то дальше уже было даже не интересно смотреть :)